# Passing string from class to main activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass something from one class to my MainActivity, but it doesn't seem to work, I don't understand why.
I have my GPS Tracker on another class (not the MainActivity) in order to reuse it.
When the location changes, I want my other class to call a method from within the MainActivity to update my UI.

I summarized my code like that :

```
 My MAIN ACTIVITY :

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView tv;
EditText et;
Button btun;
int arg0;
int stuff;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    btun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btun);
    btun.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void setter(int stuff) {
    tv.setText(stuff);
}

public void setText(int _stuff) {
    _stuff = stuff;
    setter(_stuff);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Getter get = new Getter();
    get.getInfo(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()));
}
```

The other Class :

```
public class Getter {

int _getString;
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

public void getInfo(int getString) {
    _getString = getString * 8;
    main.setText(_getString);
    }
}
```

I end up having a NullPointerException in my LogCat
at :

```
- tv.setText(stuff);
- setter(_stuff);
- main.setText(_getString);
- get.getInfo(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()));
```

and I don't really know why, and above all, how to fix it.

I'll appreciate any help !

(PS : My GPS tracker thingy is working fine, it's just about invoking my setter() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiaing an Object of `MainActivity` doesn't automatically call `onCreate` method but this method is called when you start an activity using `Intent`; And using the same intent you can pass extra values. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", value);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and then in your main activity `onCreate` method:

```
String value = getIntent.getStringExtra("key");
```

**Edit:** 
In your case why don't you change your `void getInfo(int getString)` to return a `String` value i.e.

```
public class Getter {
...
...

    public String getInfo(int getString) {
        _getString = getString * 8;
        return Integer.toString(_getString);
    }
}
```

and then in `onClick` event of `MainActivity` bind this returned text to `TextView`

Comment: Even if my Getter Class isn't an activity ?

Comment: nope, in that case you do not need an intent, just instantiate an object and call setter method

Comment: but in order to initialize the views (textviews, editbutton etc) you do need to call it like an Activity so that these views can be initialized

Comment: So the only option is using an intent ?

Comment: yes! how else one can inflate layout, find and init views then?

Comment: Hmm okay, since the phone displayed the main UI, I thought it had infalted the layout and initialized the views :(

Comment: no but you can change your Getter.getInfo to return a String value and then onClick event of your MainActivity bind this value to TextView, it is that simple!

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because the MainActivity's onCreate()-Method hasn't been called. Therefore the tv is still null causing the NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here. main is an Activity, but it should be the MainActivity calling this object.

```
public class Getter {

int _getString;
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

public void getInfo(int getString) {
    _getString = getString * 8;
    main.setText(_getString);
    }
}
```

I cannot really make out what you are trying to achieve in the Getter class, but either:

1: Pass the Activity instance to the object

```
public class Getter {
        int _getString;
        MainActivity _main = null;

        public Getter(MainActivity main) {
            _main = main;
        }

        public void getInfo(int getString) {
            _getString = getString * 8;
            _main.setText(_getString);
        }
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Getter get = new Getter(this);
    get.getInfo(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()));
}
```

or

2: set the text in the Activity and only get the value from the Getter (My choice)

```
public class Getter {
    int _getString;
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    public void getInfo(int getString) {
        return getString * 8;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Getter get = new Getter();
    int info = get.getInfo(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()));  
    setText(Integer.toString(info));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Application Class or create a separate Class and declare a static variable in it. Use getter & setter methods to get the value. To update the Textview in mainacivity from other class pass the texview reference variable from main activity and put null check condition  in other class if textview is not null then update the value.